# D3 multi-line tooltip for SVG element in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I'm attempting the same than this [question](http://D3%20multi-line%20tooltip%20for%20SVG%20element), for make an example, i go to use the same code of the question (the question is basically the same, but the answer is not good for IE9).

I have this code:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class","bar")
.append("title").text(function(d){ return "Line One X:" + d.x + "\nLine Two Y:" + d.y});
```

It works in chrome and firefox but IE ignore line break. I try more things like this:

```
var titulo = svg.append("svg:title");
titulo.append("tspan").text("AA");
titulo.append("br");
titulo.append("tspan).text("BB");
```

Here again IE completely ignores the br.

The friendly solution to IE11 is this:

```css
tspan:nth-child(2n) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
      <title><tspan>This is line 1</tspan>
<tspan>This is line 2</tspan>
<tspan>This is line 3</tspan>
<tspan>This is line 4</tspan></title>
    </rect>
  </svg>
```

But the autor of answer say

> Unfortunately it still renders as a single line in IE9-10

I need a solution working in IE9.